# Advantages of GLS Estimator for OLS in the Presence of Violated Spherical Assumption

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, linear, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

Let be the linear model given by:
$$y_i = x_i'\beta + \varepsilon_i$$
Using its matrix form, consider strictly exogenous assumption and spherical assumption, respectivelly:
$$E[\varepsilon | X]=0, \quad E[\varepsilon \varepsilon'|X]= \sigma^2 I_n$$
We know that the spherical assumption is equivalent to i) $E[\varepsilon_i^2|X]= \sigma^2$, and ii) $E[\varepsilon_i \varepsilon_j|X]=0$, $i \neq j$.

Under these conditions we have that the OLS estimator is BLUE. However, if the spherical condition is violated, we still have the unbiased OLS estimator, but we no longer have efficiency.  Thus, through an appropriate transformation of the original model, we can correct this problem using the GLS estimator. The GLS estimator will be BLUE, therefore, it will be efficient.

I'm having enormous difficulty visualizing the advantage of the GLS estimator. I understand well that the estimator is advantageous in itself, due to the fact that it is BLUE in the new transformed model, but I believe that my interest is still in the OLS estimator of the original model.

So, I want to understand what is the advantage of using GLS for the OLS estimator of the original model? In other words, given that our original model OLS estimator is still unbiased but inefficient, what is the advantage of using the GLS efficiency?

Comment: Are you asking about the merits of using an efficient estimator? I.a., you get smaller standard errors, which will produce larger t-statistics and hence better chances of detecting wrong null hypotheses (more power) or narrower and hence more informative confidence intervals.

Comment: Your comment is interesting, thank you.  It reinforces to me the importance of the efficiency of the GLS estimator in testing hypotheses.  But what I was wondering is what is the gain that the OLS estimator (unbiased, but inefficient) obtains from the efficiency of the GLS estimator?  Ultimately, I am interested in my original model and not the transformed model, whose OLS estimator is the GLS.

Comment: I think you may need to distinguish more clearly between estimator and model. You either use the OLS *estimator* (sometimes people talk about the "OLS model", and this may be a case in point of why that is bad) or the GLS *estimator*, so that the former cannot "gain" anything from the latter.